# It can't be throw over gateway using bonding on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, networking, centos, nic, centos6

I'll try to bonding(NIC RAID) on CentOS6.
(It can meet preconditions to connect the Internet with eachother NICs.)
I set some parameters in some files, which are "/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf", 
"/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0","/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0",
"/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1", ..., and "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth3".

In "/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf" is

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bonding mode=1 miimon=200 primary=eth0
```

In "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0" is

```
DEVICE=bond0
IPADDR=192.168.1.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.1
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=no
```

In "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1" is

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
HADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx
DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.1
```

I set same parameters "/.../ifcfg-eth1", "/.../ifcfg-eth2" and "/.../ifcfg-eth3" except of "DEVICE"and HADDR.

After I restert network devices with "service network restart".
then show in display "Devide not Managed by NetworkManager". so I did reboot the machine. 
As I check them with some operations.

1. I input "ifconfig -a", the result is normal.
2. I input "ping xxx.xxx.1.1(Gateway server IP Address), the result is
   normal.
3. I input "ping 216.239.27.104(the IP Address is Google's server)",
   the result is Error.(DNS wasn't system down then)
4. I input "ping google.com", the result is Error.
5. I input "dig", the result is normal(DNS server's IP Address was
   showed)

I seem this problem coase by Gateway's IP Address, But I don't know the way how to.
And my solution is speculation.

Please tell me how to do for resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a server where the GUI is installed.  I believe NetworkManager is hijacking.

yum list | grep -i networkmanager

See if it's installed, you can try stopping the process or removing it if not using GUI.  Have had similar issue.